# Alert a message after ajax callback

Tags: forms, ajax

With the code below I managed to alert the message but after that the form does not work properly, after the submit it redirects me to $base_url/system/ajax and a json array is displayed.

```
$form['submitted']['test']['#ajax'] = array
        (
           'callback' => '_test',
           'wrapper' => 'nimportequi',
           'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => '')
        );
```

and the callback:

```
function _test($form, $form_state){
    $commands = array();
     $text = "";
     $alert = 0;
     if (valid_email_address($form['submitted']['email']['#value']) !== FALSE)
     {
        $result = user_load_by_mail($form['submitted']['email']['#value']);
        $text = ($result !== FALSE)?$alert=1:"Based on your email, you are not a member yet!";
     }
     else 
        $text = "Based on your email, you are not a member!";
     if ($alert != 1 && $form_state['values']['submitted']['member'] == 1)
     {
        $commands[]=ajax_command_alert($text);
       // $commands[] = ajax_command_data("#foo", 'label_radio', '1');
     }
     $form_state['rebuild'] == TRUE;
     return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Also i am using a rule when the form is submitted. What am i doing wrong ? I cannot figure it out…

Comment: can you post what you have in the javascript firebug console when you click on the submit? Maybe there are some indications there

Comment: @MikaA. there's nothing. As i said the alert window is fired but the form does not work properly after i hit ok on the alert window. If i click submit it gets me to system/ajax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had a call like :

```
$form['#action'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and this was causing that after second submit the variable will take the value:

```
$form['#action'] = 'system/ajax';
```

changing this to correct behavior solved my issue like below.

```
 if (!isset($form_state['values']))
    $form['#action'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
else
    $form['#action'] = $custom_url;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the ajax callback in the submit button of the form like this:

**Edit**

```
$form['radio_buttons']['#ajax'] = array (
  'callback' => '_test',
  'wrapper' => 'nimportequi',
  'event' => 'change',
  'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => ''),
);
```

This will ensure that when a radio button is clicked your ajax callback will be executed. Selecting radio buttons will give alert message, therefore the ajax callback should be applied to radio buttons.

Your ajax callback seems ok.

Comment: thank you for the answer , but that's not what i want to do . The ajax callback should be placed on some radio buttons , because after someone selects an option i want to alert him with a message based on another value from the form . The problem is that the alert box if fired and after the alert is displayed on form submission it redirects me to system/ajax, which is wrong. Also i forgot to say that i am using rules for that form . Could this be a problem ?

Comment: what you are doing in that rule?

Comment: adds some nodes , redirects and shows a message !

Comment: not sure, may be the redirect that you are doing in the rule is causing the error. for debug purpose disable the rule and submit the form

Comment: i don't think that the rule is the problem , because i have a captcha on that form , and what i am trying to do is submit the form with wrong captchas and still the same thing happens , redirects me to system/ajax.

Comment: this means that captcha checking is not executed.. are doing custom coding in the submit handler of the form?

Comment: but if i write wrong captcha , after first submit it it tells me that the captcha was wrong and form (rule) not sumitted. After the second wrong try it redirects me to system/ajax.

Comment: the action of the form is set to the current url and also there is another form in the page which uses ajax.

Comment: so do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: hey , what do you mean by "should be applied on the radio button form elements." ?

Comment: I knew that you will missunderstand me... Is there a way to return the new form element and also to popup an alert message in the callback ?

Comment: I dont think so, you cannot do two return in one PHP function

Comment: I see that you are stuck in this problem for days, I suggest you should do stepwise debugging using devel module and check where is the break in form submit or callback. And mention those in your question.

Comment: I did and i cannot understand the behaviour of it. If i remove the ajax callback or i do not choose any option in radio buttons in form everything works great , but if i do the callback no matter what is in the callback after second submission of the form it gets me to that system/ajax page. It really bothers me ...

Comment: Why so many upvotes ? The answer is not relevant to the question, because the ajax call is applied to radio buttons . In my question radio_buttons are called "test"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the '#ajax' on the select form element, not the submit.

eg.

```
$form['myselect'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(1, 2),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_test',
    'event' => 'change',
  ),
);

function _test($form, $form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[]=ajax_command_alert('testing');
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Woops.....I'm drunk right now.....haha...well...now you know how to do it with a slect too :)